# What's the difference between 補給, 補充, 補足, 補完?

Tags: word-choice

According to Denshi Jisho, they mean "supplementation" but I wonder if there is any difference in their nuances.

Here are some examples where they are used:

1. 小まめに**補給**することが大切です。
2. 職員の欠員を**補充**するために広告を出した。
3. この件について**補足**の説明をさせてください。
4. 学校での教育を**補完**する役割が塾にはある。

Comment: Also related are 補填 and 補償.

Answer (score 5):

They're quite different words. Grammatically, all of them are used as verbs with `～する`.

**`補充`** is better translated as *to replenish*, that is to refill something when the number/amount of them have decreased.

**`補給`** is a special case of `補充`, whose replenishment is intended for immediate consumption. Typical ones I imagine are water for marathon runners, and ammo for front-line soldiers. You can use `補充` instead of `補給`, but not necessarily vice versa.

If `補給` is used without object, it's usually considered as *to take nourishment*.

**`補足`** is *to add words as afterthoughts*. You can only use it for adding information.

**`補完`** is *to complement with something obverse*.

---

**Supplementation on krnk's comment:**
`補填` is *to make good a deficit*, and `補償` is *to compensate (for a damage)*.

Comment: Could you clarify "Never used outside language" ?

Comment: Edited. Hope it's made clear now.

Comment: It still isn't clear. Do you mean not used outside of written works?

Comment: What I meant was you can only use it for adding "words", but not "water", "food", "materials" and anything else. How do you say it in good English?

Comment: I think comparing words with those examples is a good way to explain.

Comment: I see plenty of example sentences in the dictionary for 補足 that have nothing to do with words...

Comment: @Flaw & istrasci A good sleep brought me with a better word: "information". Thanks for commenting.